# Update user's action history in two different models

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a List model

```
const listSchema = new Schema({
    user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Users', required: true },
    entries: [listEntry]
})
const List = mongoose.model('Lists', listSchema);
```

And the entry looks like this

```
const listEntry = new Schema({
    _id: false,
    book: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Books', required: true, unique: true },
    note: { type: Number, default: null, max: 21 },
    status: String,
    history: [Object] 
})
```

A listEntry can be modified whenever the user changes the note,  the status, etc.

I wanted to push the history of every action the user does inside the listEntry but ALSO in the User

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    userId: { type: String, required: true },
    history: [Object]
})
const User = mongoose.model('Users', userSchema);
```

The user history would contain ALL ListEntry's histories (all the actions of the account). A ListEntry's history would contain only the 'local' actions of the book.

I thought about using .post on the listSchema, but I don't know how to find the right ListEntry inside of it. The same would apply on a .post() on the UserSchema as I would need to go through the history.

Should I change my model modelisation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by creating a single History model and using [Virtuals](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/virtuals.html) in needed models.

By referencing the _id of the User as well as the List or any other component, I'm able to create this history.